# .htaccess can't access my index

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to limit which files and/or subfolders can be accessed within a directory through .htaccess. My issue is that once I set up "Deny All" but "Allow" index.php to be accessed, when I simply enter site.com/folder I get a 403 error instead of reaching index.php. How can I restore the default redirect to index without messing the rules in my .htaccess file!?

```
<Files ~ "^.*">

    #Deny Access to Everything
    Order Allow,Deny 
        Deny from all 

</Files>

<Files ~ "^index\.php|^changepass\.php|^wr\.php|^wrs\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.pdf">

    #Allow Exceptions
    Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all

</Files>

<Files ~ "^splif\.php">

    #Allow Specific Exception
    Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all

    #Request Authentication 
    AuthUserFile /home/path/secret/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName EnterPassword
    AuthType Basic
        require user admin

</Files>
```

Comment: Instead of playing with htaccess, why don't you move all your protected files and folders out of the wwwroot?

Comment: ...what redirect?

Comment: @Dainis Abols I would have moved it out, but there are a lot of other files dependent on these ones. So it's much easier to limit the access! My only alternative is to write manually which files should be blocked, but that is undesirable!

Comment: @Svish I mean the default redirect a website does to index.php when you access a root folder that contains it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, my solution was to make some extra .htaccess files in the subfolders with only "Order Allow,Deny Deny from all" and modify Files ~ "^.*" into Files ~ "php". This way I block all other .php I don't want people to snoop into and leave the images, javascript and other format files accessible only by name!